# Apply Filter to amCharts XY Chart Scrollbar unselected area

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I am using an amCharts4 `XYChartScrollbar`, and I have a couple of series that I have added to the scrollbar. It works fine, as intended. However, I am having a problem with styling.

I would like the `XYChartScrollbar` to be full-color series for all parts of the graph that are currently selected within the Scrollbar's range. All parts of the graph outside of the selected area, I would like to remain gray-scale.

Initially, the entire `XYChartScrollbar` is gray-scale due to the applied `DesaturateFilter` as mentioned in the [documentation here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/customizing-chart-scrollbar/#Re_enabling_colors). What I would like to do is have the selected areas of the Scrollbar with their original colors (no `DesaturateFilter`) but still have the unselected areas of the Scrollbar appear to be gray-scale (yes `DesaturateFilter`). Is it possible to do this?

I have re-enabled colors on the Scrollbar series by using the following snippet:

```
this.chart.scrollbarX.scrollbarChart.plotContainer.filters.clear()
```

This restores color to the series in the Scrollbar chart.

Now, to re-enable the gray-scale filters for only the unselected parts of the graph, I have tried using filters on certain areas of the `XYChartScrollbar`. There is the [unseletedArea](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/customizing-chart-scrollbar/#Unselected_area) property which is a `Sprite` that can receive filters. However, applying a filter as follows does not impact the chart colors themselves:

```
  const filter = new am4core.DesaturateFilter()
  filter.saturation = 1
  console.log(this.chart.scrollbarX.unselectedOverlay.filters)
  this.chart.scrollbarX.unselectedOverlay.filters.push(filter)
```

I believe because the `unselectedOverlay` is simply just an overlay and has no impact on the chart itself.

I'm not sure what else I can do here. Is there any way to achieve this desired result?